# SHA-1 hash where each of the first 16 bytes is even

Tags: hash, sha-1

Is it possible for a SHA-1 hash to have the first 16 characters with a character code $c$ where $c \bmod 2 = 0$?

So given the hash, `hash[i] % 2` must be 0 for all 16 characters.

Comment: Do you mean raw bytes or hex characters?

Answer (score 5):

An input with the property you are looking for can easily be found by brute force:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from hashlib import sha1

def good(s):
    for c in sha1(s).digest():
        if ord(c) & 1:
            return False
    return True

for n in xrange(10**7):
    if good(str(n)):
        print n
        raise SystemExit
```

To double check the correctness of the result I used this command:

```
printf 1014746 | sha1sum | grep '^\(.[02468ace]\)*  -$'
```

Answer (score 3):

In a SHA-1 hash, or any decent cryptographic hash, there is no way to find an input such that the output matches certain bit patterns. Intuitively speaking, the transformation from an input to its hash “looks random”, we can't find patterns such as “if the input looks like this then the output looks like this”.

Therefore, if you want certain bits of the output to have certain values, there is no way other than brute force. You have to try some inputs (you can pick them any way you like: randomly, sequentially, with or without a fixed prefix or suffix, …) and calculate their hash until one suits you.

Since you want 16 bytes to have an even value, you want 16 bits to have the value 0. This means that you'll need to make about $2^{16}$ attempts to have a good chance of success.

The difficulty of finding inputs that hash to certain patterns is the basis of some protocols, such as [bitcoin mining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitcoin#Mining) (to create a bitcoin, you have to generate an input whose SHA-256 hash is within a small range — basically you need hash values whose first $N$ bits are 0).

Answer (score 1):

The output of SHA-1 isn't "characters," it's *160 bits*, usually represented as 20 *bytes*.  The fact that you're thinking about this problem in terms of "characters"—the wrong type—makes your question ambiguous about whether you mean the SHA-1 result properly speaking, or a *serialized* ASCII representation of the SHA-1 result (in hexadecimal or Base64).  I'm going to assume the binary output of the function, represented as 20 bytes.

One simplified and common way of reasoning about this is to think of a hash function like SHA-1 as a [random oracle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_oracle): a black box that assigns a consistent random result to every possible input.  Under this model, we reason about outputs just like we would reason about a sequence of 160 fair coin tosses:

- Every bit has an equal chance of being either 0 or 1;
- The outcome for every bit is independent of every other bit.

So your question then is like asking what's the chance that 16 coin tosses will produce all heads.  The answer is $2^{-16}$.  So if you blindly try distinct inputs you expect to find one such input once every $2^{16}$ tries.  It should be trivial to use brute force to find such an input.

@kasperd's example python program actually searches for a SHA-1 output where *all 20* output bytes have a zero for their least-significant bit, which means we expect one such output for every $2^{20}$ inputs.  The program is using a counter, and if we look at the result `1014746` we can see that $\log_2(1014746) \approx 19.95$, i.e., the program succeeded after about $2^{19.95}$ tries.

Comment: Do we actually need to model SHA-1 as a random oracle for this, wouldn't a PRF suffice?

Comment: I don't see how the PRF model fits. What would be the indexed family of functions?  What would be the secret key?  I'd say this question is more like finding a preimage for an odd truncation of SHA-1.

Comment: @SEJPM: And thinking about it some more, I'm saying that an *attacker* that models SHA-1 as a random oracle can use a generic preimage attack to find an suitable input string in a practical amount of time. I understand there are qualms about a *defender* modeling a hash function as a random oracle, but they shouldn't apply here.